# Differentiating a triangular wave

Tags: fourier-series

I was really stuck and tried many times to differentiate the following series, and tried to convince myself that the differential form of a triangular wave is the square wave.

But I couldn't work it out as I found those sins and cos dont match up

Square wave has this form

[image: square wave]

triangular wave has the following form

[image: triangular]

Can anyone show me how you differentiate triangular wave to get square? they are both sines.... I would imagine after differentiation you get a cos series for triangular wave.
Thanks every one for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with some graphical reasoning. When you plot these square and triangular waves, you'll notice that they need to be $\pi/2$ out of phase in order for the square wave to match up with the slope of the triangular wave; there will also be some vertical scaling you need to apply. This phase shift will explain why they are both $\sin$ series, and the scaling explains the change from $8$ to $4$.

Alternatively, just compute the derivative of the triangular wave series and show that it is a transformed square wave.

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that a sine wave is the same as a cosine wave, but shifted by $\frac \pi 2$  As the triangle wave is odd, the derivative of the square wave is even (plot it) so should be a sum of cosines.